# characteristic of ${\mathbb Z_2 }$ is $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I tried to solve the
characteristic  of ${ \mathbb Z_p }$ = $0$ or prime $p$ .

In ${ \mathbb Z_2 },$ nothing gives me $0$ where $nr = 0$ and $n \ne 0,$ where ${  n , r \in R }$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: what you wrote is difficult to understand, but $2\times1=1+1=0$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, where the characteristic is $2$

Comment: ${ z_2  }$ have { [ 0 ] , [ 1 ] } 
which 0 x 0 = 0 x 1 = 0  and  from defination of char >>> nr = 0 which n! 0 
and 1 * 1 = 1 not zero 
so char is 0 
are my steps is right ?

Comment: as I said, in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $1+1=0$, so the characteristic is $2$; I think it would be easier to understand what you write if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the characteristic of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is $n$; in particular, the characteristic of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is $2$.

The [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) of a ring is the smallest $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n1=\underbrace{1+...+1}_{n \text{ times}}=0,$

where $1$ is the multiplicative identity and $0$ is the additive identity in the ring.

(If no such $n$ exists, the characteristic is $0$.)

You might have been confused because you were thinking of $n$ in the ring, not in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic is not in the set, it is from positive integers. If there is not a positive integer n such that n.a=0 for all a element of R, then char R=0

Comment: It is about being Z-module, every abelian group can be Z module (n times adding it) so if group is finite then there must be a positive integer s.t. n.a=a+a+...+a=0 for every element a of G, we say characteristic for minimum n.